# How do you combine resetting NVRAM and also boot from USB?

Tags: usb, mac-mini, recovery, startup, internet-recovery

I have a Mac Mini 2018 and a new monitor with a DVI cable.

Currently, my Mac Mini is completely reset, so I need to reinstall macOS.

I have two problems:

1. Screen is flickering and can't see anything on the screen
2. Seeing -1008f error while doing recovery.

The first issue can be resolved by resetting NVRAM using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on boot.

I am trying to resolve the second issue as well by booting with a USB or doing the latest Internet Recovery, however, I can't boot with any other keys than <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> because otherwise, I can not see the screen at all.

Does anyone have any idea how to reset NVRAM and boot with USB at the same time?

Comment: Sounds like there's a hardware problem. However: the NVRAM contains the information about which volume is the startup. So if you reset it, the Mac won't go to the USB first. 2018 Macs also have a SecureBoot Options, which you need to configure to allow external boot drives. You shouldn't normally need to erase the entire internal device.

Comment: Resetting NVRAM itself causes a second boot - you could try holding Opt at that point. Error -1008f is 'couldn't connect' so try wiring up to Ethernet to get to Internet Recpovery - that way you won't need a boot USB. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206989

Comment: @benwiggy I can not see screen when I boot with other than cmd+option+p+r ...

Comment: What is the display and how is it connected?

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried holding opt on second boot already, but that didn't work out. Seems like it only uses the first key combination. And I already have ethernet connected, and 1008f is displayed after around 10mins of recovery

Comment: @benwiggy it's unis 23" montior, and i am using dvi->hdmi converter to plug into my mac

Comment: You may need to use Apple Configurator (on a 2nd Mac, connected to the Mini) in order to restore the firmware and/or OS. Would be useful to know the back story of what happened to the Mac, and how/why it was wiped.

Comment: @benwiggy does apple configurator work with macmini as well? I do have a macbook, so if i can do something with that, it would be nice. Regarding wipe, I did that because I had to ship it before relocation.

Comment: Yes, Config 2 works with T2 Minis. Not sure why shipping the drive should require erasing the entire SSD. It's encrypted, so no one can read it.  Maybe wipe just the Data volume, but not everything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141249/discussion-between-emil-and-benwiggy).

Comment: I was able to figure it out by doing DFU restore using my other macbook. It was because primary drive was wiped out and wasn't created. I managed to land on to disk utility after doing DFU restore, set up volumes for system and it was all good after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an answer for everyone else experiencing a `-1008F` error. It was happening because the primary volume was wiped in Disk Utility.

Once you manage to get into Disk Utility and set up the primary volume, you will be able to install the system.

I used DFU restore to get into Disk Utility because any other USB boot or startup disks did not work out.

For more information about DFU restore, see Apple's Support article "[Revive or restore a Mac with Apple silicon using Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-mac/revive-or-restore-a-mac-with-apple-silicon-apdd5f3c75ad/mac)".

Answer (score 0):

If after one NVRAM reset, the video is not clear you almost certainly have a hardware issue that's not likely to be resolved by the reinstallation. It's unlikely but possible the issue is with the display and not the Mac, can you try another cable / display?

Ideally, you would take this Mac to another to do the erase / make a bootable drive and bring that already working drive to the Mac to validate that it's not software and you need service.

I agree with the comments, the [error indicates a network error getting to internet recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT206989) so if you can't get a repair estimate easily, perhaps taking the Mac to another network to try one restore again would be worth the time.

You also may wish to check your AppleID online to be sure it's not activation lock causing the registration issue. If this wasn't managed by your AppleID - official service will be the only way you'll know what's the issue as they can try restore from a known good OS or a known good internet connection that works for recovery.